# Find constant k if given a continuous piecewise function

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

Seems like an easy question but I'm stumped. The answer is $5$ and I can't seem to get to it. Of course, I know I must take the limit of the top function and that it should be equal to k but I can't evaluate the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the fraction into two parts, and use the fact that $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin t}{t} =1 $:

$$\frac{x^2\sin(5/x)}{\sin kx} +\frac{25x}{\sin kx}\\ \to x^2 \cdot \frac{\sin(5/x)}{kx} +\frac{25x}{kx} \\ =\frac xk \sin (5/x)+\frac{25}{k} \\ \to0+\frac{25}{k}$$

Then for continuity, $$\frac{25}{k} = k \implies k=5$$

Comment: What happened to $sin$ in the denominator from line 2 onwards? @Tavish

Comment: @user737163 I replaced the sine with its argument, which I can do as $$\sin(kx) = \frac{\sin (kx)}{kx} \times kx \to 1\times kx $$

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't notice I can do that. Thanks for the answer!